# How to override Default Bootstrap.css styles with our userdefined style

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `input-group input-group-lg` classes to add styles to `textarea`.

The border is not being applied to the `textarea`.

Default value for the border is 0.
in bootstrap.css if we modify

```
.input-group .form-control:first-child{
    border:1;
}
```

Then i am getting border. How can i apply this style to `my_styles.css` which is in my project.

I pasted above selector in my css file and used !important also and not getting border.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `my_styles.css` the last CSS stylesheet that is imported? (you MUST make it the last one so it overrides the Bootstrap defaults)

Answer (score 2):

You defined `border: 1`, what 1? One apple, one meter, one pixel?

Complete border definition is `border: 1px solid #000` (width type color), if you only want to change border width, use `border-width: 1px;`.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `!important` unless you **really really** have to.

To override the existing styles, make sure you load your CSS files **after** the bootstrap one. Then, make sure your rules are **at least as specific** as those in the original CSS file, only like that you can override them.

Here is a nice tool for comparing specificity: http://specificity.keegan.st/

Also, make sure you follow the proper syntax for each CSS rule. The example you've shown is not valid CSS therefore it should not work, ever. Look at @panther's answer for detailed explanation.